# Styling each <li> a different way with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

weird little bug I can't figure out, I have the following line:

```
$("#ingredientlist").append('<li>' + value + ' parts ' + capitalize(index + '') + '</li>').css("color", curColor);
```

Basically, in a previous statement I get `curColor`, which is different depending on what value I'm on. I checked the colors and they're different each time. I want each `<li>` to be styled to a specific color, so I tried setting the .css() to that, but all my entries are the same color. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are appending `li` to `$("#ingredientlist")` then setting its `color`

You need to set color of `li` not its parent.

*Use*

```
$("#ingredientlist").append(
    $('<li></li>')
        .text(value + ' parts ' + capitalize(index + ''))
        .css("color", curColor)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because `append()` returns the parent element, not the one which was appended. This means that your code is actually setting the `color` of the `#ingredientlist` element, not the `li`. Try this instead:

```
$('<li  />', { text: value + ' parts ' + capitalize(index + '') })
    .css('color', curColor)
    .appendTo('#ingredientlist');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the `.css` call to the `#ingredientlist` set, not the `li` you're appending.

Instead:

```
$("#ingredientlist").append($('<li>' + value + ' parts ' + capitalize(index + '') + '</li>').css("color", curColor));
// Changes -----------------^^-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Breaking that up into parts just to make it clearer:

```
var $li = $('<li>' + value + ' parts ' + capitalize(index + '') + '</li>');
$li.css("color", curColor);
$("#ingredientlist").append($li);
```